# Atomics and memory barriers in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, atomic, memory-barriers, compute-shader

I'm using a `shared uint` variable to total up values from each invocation in my compute shader's work group, however I'm struggling to understand where to put memory barriers and what kinds to use.

Firstly, do I need to use memory barriers even when using atomic functions, or is an `atomicAdd(total, 1)` safe?

If I do need memory barriers, which do I need and where do I need to put them? Is this enough to ensure consistency between invocations?

```
atomicAdd(total, 1);
groupMemoryBarrier(); // Does it go before or after? Or both?
```

Or do I need a call to `barrier()` too?

```
atomicAdd(total, 1);
groupMemoryBarrier();
barrier();
```

If it matters, the variable is not explicitly read until the end of the work group's execution (which will have a `barrier()` before and thus be synchronized). However, I believe `atomicAdd` counts as reading as it relies on the previous value.

An explanation of exactly what `groupMemoryBarrier` does and how it applies here would be much appreciated.